# How to speed/fix my macro that compares 2 columns and removes duplicates in first column

Tags: vba, excel

I have 2 questions.

1. Why does my macro only delete roughly 50% of the duplicates on the first run through? When I run it again, it completes and deletes the rest of them. (I have tried with 2,000 lines and with 9,000 lines, the result is the same, only 50% the first try, the other 50% the second)
2. I know that I'm sifting through a large amount of data (up to 9,000+ in Column A and B) but is there anything glaring that looks like I could change to speed things up? Currently the first run takes about 5 minutes to run through, the second run takes 2 minutes, at which point I have the correct data. I currently have my master macro setup to run this macro twice.

   ```
   Sub RemoveDuplicateFromOneColumnComparingWithAnother()
   'Delete column header I don't need'
   Rows("1:1").Select
   Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
   'First I remove duplicates from Column B, Column A already has only Unique values' 

   Columns("B:B").Select
   ActiveSheet.Range("B:B").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:= _
   xlNo
   'Now I compare columns A and B, and and delete any matching values from column A'
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   Dim rngCell As Range
   Dim rngCheck As Range
   For Each rngCell In Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns(2).Cells
   If Not IsEmpty(rngCell) Then
       Do
           Set rngCheck = Nothing
           On Error Resume Next
           Set rngCheck = Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns(1).Find("*" & rngCell.Value & "*")
           rngCheck.ClearContents
           Err.Clear: On Error GoTo -1: On Error GoTo 0
       Loop Until rngCheck Is Nothing

   End If
   Next rngCell
   Set rngCell = Nothing
   Set rngCheck = Nothing

   End Sub
   ```

Comment: Can you please give more details as to what you're trying to accomplish? It looks like you should rather be doing `Range("A:B").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1,2), Header:=XlNo`. Maybe you can link an image (use imgur.com since your rep is low) to show the sample data?

Comment: If speed is your aim, then looping through cells is not the way to go.  For large amounts of data, consider using arrays,  High level steps - 1.  Remove dupes in col B as you are now.  2. Read column A into an array and column B into an array.  3.  Nested loop checking if values in array A exist in Array C, if not, write unique value to array C.  4.  Delete old Column A values 5.  Put Array C into column A.  Order of magnitude of performance benefit is in the 100's if not 1000's times faster (Have converted procedures with this method from 20 mins to 4 seconds run time)

Comment: Basically I am pulling unique values from a list of 400,000 lines onto Sheet 2 Column A. in Column B I'm pulling over all values from Column H if Column AM is not blank.  The end result is A has unique values, B has many duplicates.  I don't care about the duplicates in Column B, I simply want to delete duplicate values from column A when comparing with Column B.

Comment: Joseph4tw, I've tried that, but unfortunately it just doesn't work. I'm still left with many cells in column A that match cells in Column B. I'm not sure why the basic function doesn't work. I know after I'm done, I should be at 2-3 thousand. When I run that macro I'm still at 33,000 lines.

Comment: Mark, that sounds like a good way to go. I'll look around and see if I can find some coding to do that. I'm new enough to VBA to be able to read what most of it does, but not experienced enough to create it from scratch. I'll see if I can find some stuff and modify it.

Comment: Mark Moore- For my education, if you don't mind. Your method is doing the comparison by loops still, correct? Is this method faster simply because it loops through arrays rather than cells? I may have uses for this method if so.

Comment: I think I actually answered my own question. I input =randbetween(1,50000) in range a1:b25000, nested loops to check A vs B and write duplicates to C. When looping through cells it took 1133 seconds (almost 19 mins). When performing the same by writing to arrays and nesting loops to compare arrays, then writing the duplicates to a new array and writing that array to column C, this took 26 secs.

Comment: Kyle, I'm running into issues comparing the arrays. Would you mind posting what nested loop you used to compare them and write the duplicates to C? I'd like to compare.

Answer (score 0):

I think your nested Do...Loop is slowing this down. I actually don't see a need to loop there at all.

```
On Error Resume Next
If Not IsEmpty(rngCell) Then
    set rngcheck = Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns(1).Find("*" & rngCell.Value & "*")
    If Not rngcheck is Nothing then
        rngcheck.ClearContents
    End if
End If
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice Kyle! Unfortunately when I run your suggestion, it errors out with "Run-time error '13': Type mismatch" on your If Not line after 5 minutes. Any thoughts?

Comment: Which "If Not" line did you get the error on? Try the above. I believe that will correct the issue.

Comment: yeah that fixed it. It's still taking a bit, I may try the Array Mark Mentioned. Gonna do some research.